# Why is the cow considered holy when one of it's births are by the killings of Brahmins?

Tags: scripture

You can find this within the Manusmriti chapter 12 verse 125:
He who kills a Brāhmaṇa enters the womb of a dog, a pig, an ass, a camel, a cow, a goat, a sheep, a deer or a bird, or that of a Caṇḍāla or a Pukkasa.
So if killing a Brahmin is a sin and a person who kills a Brahmin can be born as a cow then how can the cow be holy?

Comment: Maybe jiva is unholy but the body or position it occupies as cow is holy? Like once you occupy the post of president no matter who u r but u r to be respected and also cannot be charged with crimes by courts.

Comment: @Draupadi is this a question or an answer or an attempt at an answer?

Comment: it is something I just thought after reading your question. Maybe as a pointer to an answer

Comment: @Draupadi well then it sounds good bcuz I can't find any other possible answer so thanks!